# Should linked websites with dynamic content be replaced with a screenshot?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, screenshot

I was looking at [this](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/2090/when-forward-secrecy-ciphers-are-used-the-torproject-website-uses-1024-bit-key) 'question', which appears to link to a website which could change in the future (I'm not sure it does, but that's neither here nor there), and I thought that if the content of that webpage changes in the future, the question would make less sense.

Another example of this is this question right here (and other meta questions) which link to Stack Exchange questions, as often a meta post will arise about an issue in a question, and subsequently the issue will be fixed, and anyone looking at the meta question will have no idea what it's really about.

Should websites with dynamic content where the important information is what it says right now be replaced with screenshots of the webpage, or also include a screenshot?

Is it worth the extra space?

> [image]

This takes up much more space now, and the question looks worse.